# I had vs I have neglected English writing skills

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

> 1. Since I started learning English, I have neglected English writing skills.
> 2. Since I started learning English, I had neglected English writing skills.

What's the difference between these sentences??

Comment: ..I think you should change your sentences, since I started speaking English, I have  neglected  English writing skills.

Comment: shouldn't it be : since I have started learning English, I have neglected...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change the sentences:

> **since I started speaking (learning) English, I have neglected my English  writing skills**
>
> **Since I started  speaking(learning)English, I had .neglected my English writing skills**

The  second sentence does not make sense.

It means you  had neglected your writing skills well before you started  speaking or learning your English. your intended meaning is not that.

The only first sentence is correct .It means that  since you started  concentrating on your speaking skills, you have neglected your writing skills .now you are concentrating more on speaking skills..In the past you concentrated more on writing skills.

Comment: The  user should have shown the reason  for down voting